# AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'roles' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nonetype

I am coding a discord moderation bot, and I'm on the anti-spam code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild
    counter = 0
    with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter += 1

        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 5:
            # tells them to stop... and mutes them.
            mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

            if not mutedRole:
                mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
                for channel in guild.channels:
                    await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False,
                                                  read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
            await message.author.add_roles(mutedRole, reason="spamming")
            await message.author.send("Stop spamming!")
            await asyncio.sleep(20)
            mutedRole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await message.author.remove_roles(mutedRole)
            await message.author.send(f" you have unmutedd from: - {message.guild.name}")
```

basically it detects spam and then mutes them.
then, I ran into an error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[_________]", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[____________]", line 38, in on_message
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

can anyone explain why it did this?

Comment: `guild` is `None`.

Comment: how do I fix that?

Comment: By sending a message in a server, not in DMs.

Comment: if I do that, I would need to add ctx, and it wouldn't work. (ctx for the `await ctx.send()`)

Comment: Why `ctx`? What's the use of `ctx`  there? Just send it to the channel where the message originated from -- `await message.channel.send(...)`

Comment: it doesn't mute the user still.

Comment: How are you supposed to mute a user in DMs?

Comment: no, I meant muting the user in the server, but them send them a DM that tells them to stop spamming. it works when I use discord.Member.ban, but somehow it doesn't when I use the mute function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import or define what roles is.
Or else it will throw error again at line
"mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")"

Comment: I've fixed it (slightly) but whenever I spam it doesn't mute the user.